# Getting maximum of multiple arrays in amibroker

Tags: amibroker

I am trying to get the maximum of 6 amibroker arrays `A, B, C, D, E, F.`

Below is my code;

```
maximum = Max(Max(A, B), Max(C, D) );
maximum = Max(Max(maximum, E), F);
```

I find the code somewhat ugly.
What are some other ways to code this?

I am using Amibroker ver6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a look at [Highest](https://www.amibroker.com/guide/afl/highest.html) (if you need the highest value in the whole array), [HighestSince](https://www.amibroker.com/guide/afl/highestsince.html) (if you need the highest since a certain condition) or [HHV](https://www.amibroker.com/guide/afl/hhv.html) (if you need the highest value in x bars).

```
MaxA = Highest(A);
MaxB = Highest(B);
MaxC = Highest(C);
MaxD = Highest(D);
MaxE = Highest(E);
MaxF = Highest(F);
Max = Max(MaxA,Max(MaxB,Max(MaxC,Max(MaxD,Max(MaxE, MaxF)))));
```